# How to find the colspan value from the html content in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How to find the value of colspan from the html table column
I have tried

```
<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>
```

But what to add here to get the colspan value irrespective of location?
EDIT

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" align="center">
               2013
            </th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
               2012
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Tried

```
<tr[^>]*>\s*<t(d|h)[^>].*?colspan=['"](\d+)['"].*?>\s*(.*?)\s*</t(\1)>\s*</tr>
```

But this will not work if there is no quote like

```
 <td colspan=2 align="center">
                   2012
                </td>
```

Comment: Regex is not best choice for parsing html. Can you provide sample html you are trying to parse?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy What happened to _lazybrezovsky_? It was cooler than your name `:)`

Comment: Don't use regex (or other string-methods) to parse HTML, don't reinvent the wheel and use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @SonerGönül :)) Agree, *lazybereozvsky* is cooler. Can't wait to change my passport to have that name)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet) for HTML parsing. Here is sample of getting all `td` elements which have `colspan` attribute. Then in a loop you can get `colspan` attribute value for each cell:

```
HtmlDocument hdoc = new HtmlDocument();
hdoc.Load("index.html");
var cells = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@colspan]");
foreach(var cell in cells)
   string colspan = cell.Attributes["colspan"].Value;
```

UPDATE: For your sample HTML this code will find single cell and colspan will have value `2`

Comment: want to use only regex

Comment: @user3085864 can you elaborate why you want only regex?

Comment: coz I have a string as an html content. no need to load the documents n all

Comment: @user3085864 then use `hdoc.LoadHtml(your_string)` instead of loading file. Don't [Parse Html In Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: @user3085864 You obviously haven't clicked the link with the funny characters in the comment [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609575/how-to-find-the-colspan-value-from-the-html-content-in-c#comment30840681_20609575); below your question. Please click it and read. `HtmlAgilityPack` is the best solution here, not `RegEx`.